# Condition for the existence of $n$-th root of unity over$\bmod p$

Tags: number-theory

I want to know the condition for the existence of $n$-th root $a$ over $\bmod p$.

From Fermat's little theorem, we get $a^{p-1}=1 \bmod p$. Also, from the definition of $n$-th root, we get: $a^{n}=1\mod p$.

Thus, we get $p-1 = 0 \bmod n$ as a necessary condition.

Is this  the sufficient condition for the existence of $n$ th root?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_root_modulo_n

Comment: $n$-th root of $a$ or $n$-th root of unity?

Comment: n-th root of unity

Comment: @ueir There is somewhat of a lack of precision that your formulation is suffering from. Clearly the unity itself will always be an $n$-th root of itself for any $n \in \mathbb{N}^{*}$, so we should perhaps take your question to refer to the necessary and sufficient conditions for the existence of **non-trivial** $n$-th roots of unity; if so, this is what I describe in the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Since the group of non-zero elements $\mathbb{Z}_p^{\times}$ is cyclic of order $p-1$, your question amounts to the more general setting:

> **Problem**: given group $G$ cyclic of order $n$ (which we shall write in additive notation, for simplicity), a number $m \in \mathbb{N}^{*}$ and an arbitrary $t \in G$, will the equation $mx=t$ admit a solution $x \in G$?

The problem can be rephrased by asking whether the element $t$ belongs to the image $H$ of the endomorphism given by multiplication with the external scalar $m$ (the one sending $x$ to $mx$).

In general, this image can be **characterized as the unique subgroup of** $G$ **having order** $\frac{n}{(m,n)}$. **When considering $n$-th roots of unity in $\mathbb{Z}_p^{\times}$, they will therefore constitute a subgroup of order $\frac{p-1}{(n,\ p-1)}$, which will be trivial if and only if $p-1 |n$.**

Answer (score 1):

As stated the result is false. Consider for example $n=4,a=6,p=7$.

$a^n\equiv 1$ mod $p$, but $p-1$ is not divisible by $n$.

Answer (score 0):

If $p-1 = 0 \bmod n$, n-th root of unity can be written as $g^{(p-1)/n}$ where $g$ is the premitive root. Thus, $p-1 = 0 \bmod n$ is the requirement and sufficient condition.